# Global variable in PHP is not working

Tags: php, variables, scope, global-variables

I need to access `$layers` from inside the function `isOk($layer)`, but everything i tried the outside function variable `$layers` is ok, but inside the function, even with global is return null.

Here is the code:

```
$layers = array();
foreach($pcb['PcbFile'] as $file){
    if(!empty($file['layer'])){
        $layers[$file['layer']] = 'ok';
    }
}
// Prints OK!
var_dump($layers);

function isOk($layer){
    global $layers;
// Not OK! prints NULL
    var_dump($layers);
    if(array_key_exists($layer, $layers))
        return ' ok';
    return '';
}
// NOT OK
echo isOk('MD');
```

I always use Object orientation, but this was something so simple that i made with a simple function... Why `$layers` is not being 'received' correcly inside the function?

Comment: it depends on where you call `isOK($layer)`

Comment: I'm calling exacly after the function, and it prints null

Comment: can you paste what `$pcb['PcbFile']` contains?

Comment: I can, but i'm printing the `$layers` outside the function, and the output is: `array
  'MD' => string 'ok' (length=2)`, and inside the function is `null`

Comment: Is this code outside *any* functions?  (Keeping in mind that if even if the *code* is outside, if the *file* is included within a function, scopewise, it's still considered inside that function.)

Comment: @cHao, i'm using CakePHP, can this be the problem? but why?

Comment: @Ivan: It could be.  Try working with `$GLOBALS['layers']` rather than just `$layers`.  Or, better, see if you can make the variable local or put it in a class the functions that need it share.  I'd edited my previous comment to explain why the issue might be appearing.

Comment: @cHao I have tried with $GLOBALS, but it gives me an 'key not found' error... I can do it with classes, but i'm curious to know Why this is not working, because it's so simple...

Comment: Did you use `$GLOBALS` on the stuff that *sets* it too?

Comment: hmm..you are using cakephp, could be that the framework has another global variable called `$layers`...call the variable with a different name and try..

Comment: @Raidenace i tried with another name (crazy one), and also didn't worked...

Comment: @cHao I tried with `$GLOBALS['layers']` and it worked! but why doesen't work with `global $layers`

Comment: Could you try `echo isOk('MD', $layers);` & `function isOk($layer, $layers){` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Watch this...

HalfAssedFramework.php

```
<?php
class HalfAssedFramework {
    public static function run($path) {
        include $path;
    }
}

HalfAssedFramework::run('example.php');
```

example.php

```
<?php

$layers = array();
foreach($pcb['PcbFile'] as $file){
    if(!empty($file['layer'])){
        $layers[$file['layer']] = 'ok';
    }
}
// Prints OK!
var_dump($layers);

function isOk($layer){
    global $layers;
// Not OK! prints NULL
    var_dump($layers);
    if(array_key_exists($layer, $layers))
        return ' ok';
    return '';
}
// NOT OK
echo isOk('MD');
```

Run `example.php` directly, and it should work.  Run `HalfAssedFramework.php`, and it won't.

The problem is scope.  When `example.php` is included inside the `run` function, all the code inside it inherits the function's scope.  In that scope, `$layers` isn't global by default.

To fix this, you have a couple of options:

- If you know `example.php` will never run directly, you can say `global $layers;` at the beginning of the file.  I'm not sure whether this will work if the script is run directly, though.
- Replace `$layers` with `$GLOBALS['layers']` everywhere.
- Add `$layers` as an argument to `isOk`.
- Put this code within a class, as [suggested by Geoffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895137/319403).

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks!!! now i'm happy ^^ I'm using $GLOBALS['layers'] as it's not something REALLY important for all the pages...

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly answering the question, but have you considered *not* using globals? Globals really aren't that cool: they make your code harder to read, harder to understand and as a consequence, harder to maintain.

Consider something like that:

```
<?php

class LayerCollection
{
    private $layers;

    public function __construct($layers)
    {
        $this->layers = $layers;
    }

    public static function fromPcbFile($data)
    {
        $layers = array();

        foreach ($data['PcbFile'] as $layer) {
            if (!empty($layer)) {
                $layers[$layer] = true;
            }
        }

        return new self($layers);
    }

    public function hasLayer($layer)
    {
        return array_key_exists($layer, $this->layers);
    }
}

$layers = LayerCollection::fromPcbFile($pcb);
var_dump($layers->hasLayer('MD'));
```

Doesn't it look better? You can then proceed to enrich `LayerCollection` as you need more ways of interacting with your layers. This is not perfect, since there's `still` a static method lying around (makes testing harder, a factory would be better suited for that job), but that's a good start for a refactoring.

More about why globals are evil: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: I thought in doing this, but the function was really something 'dumb' to do... i repeat it like, 7 times... so just to dont't repeat the same code i would put in a function, but then this happens... As you have done, sure it's more secure, more elegant, and more correct... but i just wanted to understant the reason, why my variable wasn't visible on my scope even with `global`... Thanks anyway =]